# How to delete an element of an iterator object in a for loop

Tags: python

This is super simple

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
delete = False
for child in root:
    if delete:
        root.remove(child)
        continue
    if child.getchildren():
        delete = True
```

What I want, is to keep the first child and remove all subsequent ones.

But here only "alternating" elements are deleted.

With normal sequences we could use

```
for child in root[:]:
```

or in cases of objects we could use

```
from copy import deepcopy
for child in deepcopy(root):
```

But if I do that, I don't get the child instance of 'root' but only child instance of the copy, so I can't use it to delete root's children.

Please any ideas ?

PS: I use `child.getchildren()` because I need to keep the first child that has children of its own.

**EDIT**

Inspired by Ashalynd's comment below I tried simple slicing

```
for child in root[:]:
```

It worked. I was occupied with the idea that since `root` is an instance, slicing won't work.

But now I wonder why the following didn't work ?

```
from copy import copy
for child in copy(root):
```

Since shallow copy is essentially slicing itself.

Comment: `for child in root[1:]:` ?

Comment: `copy(root)` is not the same as `root[:]`. The type of the former is `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`; the type of the latter is `list`.

Comment: But that wouldn't matter in a `for` loop. The elements will essentially be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stop after a certain point:

```
for i, child in enumerate(root):
    if child.getchildren():
        pruned_children = root[:i]
        break
```

Then just use `pruned_children` from then on.

Comment: pruned_children would then be just a list, not an instance of type Element.

Comment: @martineau I was also thinking the same - root slicing wouldn't work. But it worked. Can anyone explain how/why it worked ?

Comment: @Jibin: Apparently `elementtree` `Element` objects support indexing and slicing (see [The _ElementInterface Class](http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-elementtree-ElementTree.htm#elementtree.ElementTree._ElementInterface-class)). So it's possible because `getroot()` returns an `Element` instance.

Comment: @Jibin according to your edit slicing worked, and I'm about to update my answer to reflect your edit. Take a look, and if you're happy then feel free to accept.

Comment: @Al.Sal try your example with slicing.  d = c[:] . It gives exactly same result.

Comment: @Jibin yes, that's true; slice indeed is a shallow copy. I mixed some stuff up. The original intent of my answer was to show you that you need not remove from a list you're iterating over when you can just constrain its bounds. What are you trying to use this for?

Comment: root is not a list. Its a instance of xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.